# mongodb taking 500 ms in fetching 150 records

Tags: mongodb, performance

We are using `MongoDb(3.0.6)` for the application we are using. We have around 150 entries in one of the collections, but it takes approx 500ms to fetch all of these records, which I didn't expect. Mongo is deployed on a company server. What can be done to reduce this time?

We are not getting too many reads and there is no CPU load, etc, What can be mistake which may be causing this or what config should be changes to affect these.

Here is my schema: http://pastebin.com/x18iDPKf

I am just querying all the entries, which are 160 in number. I don't think time taken is due to Mongoose or NodeJs, as when I quesry using RoboMongo, It still takes same time.

```
Output of db.<collection>.stats().size : 
223000
```

The query I am doing is:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({})
```

Comment: Are you running your MongoDB server locally, or is it hosted or something?

Comment: @JohnnyHK question is updated.

Comment: @robertklep question updated,

Comment: Can you also add the query and how you're timing it? It's also not entirely clear to me if the client (performing the query) is running on the same server as the database; if not, you should consider if there may be network issues causing the delay.

Comment: @robertklep I am fetching all the entries, using db.getCollection('collectionName').find({}), I am querying via Mongoose and calculating time difference before and after query, Also when I query from RoboMongo and seeing time in it's UI, both are most more than 500ms.

Comment: Sounds like either network issues or the server on which MongoDB is running is underdimensioned or too busy doing other things.

Comment: @robertklep In ideal cases it should be taking how much time, 50 ms?

Comment: @saurabh it really depends on record size, etc, but retrieving 200 ~1K-sized records from a local MongoDB takes my Mac about 15ms.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it shouldn't be a problem with MongoDB. It should be a temporary issue or might be due to system constraints such as Internal Memory and so on.

If still the problem exists, use Indexes on the appropriate field which you are querying.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: actually this is happening every time, I tried indexing also, but that didn't helped much and there are anyway just 200 entries, so I must be making some other silly mistake I am doing somewhere.

Comment: post your schema and your query, to get more idea on the problem

Comment: Update the question to add schema.